# Vega-lite mark not showing colors as specified

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to change the Table Bubble Plot example (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/circle_github_punchcard.html) to include an additional value for the color gradient of the mark.
I have simplified [my example in this editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AAk2mgF5zMSQYICeAAihyoSTHFlO4yuzCTrMEG-ScbCBg2AHcbZRoAMyi4dRdMfyscNRs2KIiaDTgdYxpZMiDHQTVKRRUnFFRQYgsGNTQAbVAqkABBcqY0ACYABj6lKDQARmGlZTQAZgBfBRa0ds6e-t7BtAAWXspu8anZ+fQOpS7UPu6xkCHUTe3d0-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):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Horizontally concatenated charts that show different types of discretizing scales.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2020, "c": 11, "d": 3},
      {"a": "A", "b": 2020, "c": 40.2, "d": 3},
      {"a": "A", "b": 2021, "c": 40.2, "d": 2},
      {"a": "A", "b": 2022, "c": 70.2, "d": 1},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2020, "c": 20.2, "d": 1},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2021, "c": 20.2, "d": 2},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2021, "c": 20.2, "d": 2},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2022, "c": 20.2, "d": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": 2021, "c": 20.2, "d": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": 2022, "c": 20.2, "d": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": 2022, "c": 20.2, "d": 1}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "circle",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": null,
      "axis": {"ticks": false, "domain": false, "title": null}
    },
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "ordinal"},
    "size": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "type": "threshold",
        "domain": [30, 70],
        "range": [80, 200, 320]
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "d",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "type": "threshold",
        "domain": [2, 3],
        "range": ["#FF0000", "#FBFF00", "#00FF00"]
      },
      "legend": {"title": "Threshold"}
    }
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent", "size": "independent"}}
}
```

Here you clearly see the difference between red and lightred, which I don't want. I just want one of these three colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Set the opacity to 1.

```
  "mark":{"type": "circle", "opacity":1},
```

[Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AAk2mgF5zMSQYICeAAihyoSTHFlO4yuzCTrMEG-ScbCBg2AHcbZRoAMyi4dRdMfyscNRs2KIiaDTgdYxpZMiDHQTVKRRUnFFRQYgsGNTQAbVAqkABBcqY0ACYABj6lKDQARmGlZTQAZgBfBRa0ds6e-t7BtAAWXspu8anZ+fQOpS7UPu6xkCHUTe3d0-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-YgLRQA)

Comment: This is exactly what I don’t want. I want to have the fuller color for all the marks. I know there is some irrelevant stuff in there now, but that is fine for now

Comment: I think I understand - I'll update the answer now. Is that better?